# Kendo ui grid didn't understand 1/0 as boolean true/false

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

If I give `1/0` isntead of `true/false` **Kendo UI grid** understand it as false in both values.

You can see it in [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/as8FR/2/).

Code works properly with `true/false` like in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/as8FR/3/).

Is it possible to add check for `boolean` with 1/0 values?

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't do a thing like 

record == 1 ? true: false;

Comment: For doing that I need additional loop, and need to change code any many places what can crate lot of problems in future maintenance.

Comment: Ah, well your problem is that 1 and 0 are not booleans. Until you find a way to make them booleans, or translate them to booleans you're going to have problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the template of the column like this:

```
{ 
  field: "ProductActive", 
  title: "ProductActive", 
  template: "#= !!ProductActive#" 
}
```

Here is a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/as8FR/6/

Comment: Thanks for answer. Fiddle is without template, I [added](http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/as8FR/7/). Now it write true, but when clicking on it checkbox still not checked.

Comment: Updated the fiddle to a more recent version of Kendo UI. Yours was using a two-year old version. http://jsfiddle.net/as8FR/11/